# Flexbox align (key, value) list both vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve a two way (vertical and horizontal) alignment with flexbox.

I have two examples, one using a `flexDirection`(`flex-direction`) `row`, and another using `column` and putting the data into difference sections to try and achieve my desired result.

Here's an example pen: http://codepen.io/reggi/pen/RpRNJB?editors=0010

Here's the full screen version: http://codepen.io/reggi/full/RpRNJB/

In the following screen `ExampleOne` is as desired. But it is not when the screen is smaller.

[image]

Here's the same code, with red borders around each box.

[image]

Here's what happens when the screen is shrunk, you can see that ExampleOne looses the left-sides row alignment with the right side, yet ExampleTwo maintains the row alignment when one of the side overflows to the next line.

[image]

Is there a way with flex box that I can have both of these solutions in one example?

```
const {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Text,
  View
} = ReactNative;

const {
  Component
} = React

const eos = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
})

function ExampleOne (props) {
  return (
    <View style={eos.container}>
      <View>
        {Object.keys(props.items).map((value, key) => (
          <View key={key}>
            <Text>{value}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
      <View>
        {Object.values(props.items).map((value, key) => (
          <View key={key}>
            <Text>{value}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const ets = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }
  item: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
})


function ExampleTwo (props) {
  return (
    <View style={ets.container}>
      {Object.keys(props.items).map((itemKey, key) => (
        <View key={key} style={ets.item}>
          <View>
            <Text>{itemKey}</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>{props.items[itemKey]}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}

const items = {
  "SortAs": "SGML", 
    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
    "Acronym": "SGML",
    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986"
}

class SampleApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Example One</Text>
          <ExampleOne items={items}/>
        <Text>Example Two</Text>
          <ExampleTwo items={items}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

// rendering
const rootTag = document.getElementById('react-root');
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
AppRegistry.runApplication('SampleApp', { rootTag });
```

Comment: if you want to use flex, keys and values should be in sibblings tags within a single parent so the meaning (without css or a screen reader) is there, else to spray each in different colums, meaning is lost. beside , only display:grid would allow to draw col and rows to fit each others size., flex or column css will just draw a col, and then another one. `<div><hx>key</hx><p>value</p></div>` or `<dl><dt>key</dt><dd>value</dd><-- ..more dt/dd, let css style it...  --></dl>` could be used , from there flex could easily do the expected job. if these are datas, HTML table can also be considered ...

Comment: You can also draw key - value , row by row and use display:table/table-cell. eventually white-space and or word-break ....probably more efficient than flex  bad example of the idea for example 1 http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VpjLMR?editors=0110 and http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZeOGRv?editors=1100 fromgenerated code of example 2 'flex involved ) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZeOGRv?editors=1100

Comment: @ThomasReggi you can define the width of the left column flex element in example two. Do you need to use flexbox instead of `display: table`?